# Android. объявление кнопки через класс

Tags: android, java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сделать кнопку через класс? Всё это делается без xml, ну не считая главный Layout.

```
//////////// test.Java
public class test extends Activity
{
        Button buttonTest;

        public void init(){
                buttonTest = new Button(this); // что то тут не так
        }
}

///////////// mainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{      
        Button button;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);

                test test1 = new test();

                button = new Button(this);// порядок
                // test1.init();        // снимаем коммент и весело вылетаем

        }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это правильно реализовать?

Comment: У вас оба класса наследованы от Activity. какой в этом смысл, какого эффекта вы хотите добиться? Если вы хотите создать класс представляющий собой кнопку (и в этом классе кастомизировать саму кнопку) - это одно. Если вы хотите часть функционала, относящегося к активити, вынести в другой класс, для этого должны быть причины и для этого есть свои инструменты, в частности фрагменты - это совсем другое. постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы, [описывайте цель, а не шаг](http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html#goal).

Comment: цель - вынести код с созданием кнопок в другой класс, что бы в mainActivity они создавались вызовом test1.init(); там будет массив кнопок(как будто дни календаря). пойду читать про фрагменты, Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь создать кнопку в другой активити, в конструктор даете Context, который равен null, так как вторая активити не запущена!

```
public class test{
    Button buttonTest;

    public void init(Context context){
            buttonTest = new Button(context); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!
Именно то что было нужно, всё заработало.
Ещё раз Спасибо! :)